# Python side-by-side merge of comma-delimited text files

Tags: python, text, merge

Suppose I have two text files with the content shown below.

**Text file 1:**

```
Apple, 0
Pear,  1
Orange, 0
```

**Text file 2:**

```
Apple, 1
Pear, 1
Orange, 1
```

I wish to merge them in a side-by-side fashion, keeping only the left "column", which is identical for both text files, of text file 1.  That is, I wish to produce the following merged text file.

**Merged text file:**

```
Apple, 0, 1
Pear, 1, 1
Orange, 0, 1
```

I'm trying to find how to---in a reasonably small amount of code---perform such a merge. But, in the real problem, there can be any number of text files.  How can I do this in Python?

Assumptions:

1. Every text file will have exactly the same number of rows.
2. Every text file will be a comma delimited file with exactly 1 comma per line.
3. For every row in every text file, the value to the left of the comma is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fileinput.input will take a list is files, use an ordereddict to concat all the values and maintain order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d= OrderedDict()

import fileinput
with open("joined.txt","w") as f:
    for line in fileinput.input(["file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","file4.txt"]):
        spl = line.strip().split(",")
        d.setdefault(spl[0],[])
        d[spl[0]] += spl[1:]
    for k,v in d.items():
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(k,",".join(v)))
```

If they are all in their own directory you can pass os.listdir to fileinput:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d= OrderedDict()

import fileinput
import os

with open("joined.txt","w") as f:
    for line in fileinput.input(os.listdir("path_to")):
        spl = line.strip().split(",")
        d.setdefault(spl[0],[])
        d[spl[0]] += spl[1:]
    for k,v in d.items():
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(k,",".join(v)))
```

If they are not the only files but follow a pattern you can use glob:

```
import fileinput
import os
import glob

with open("joined.txt","w") as f:
    for line in fileinput.input(glob.glob("./file*.txt")):
        spl = line.strip().split(",")
        d.setdefault(spl[0],[])
        d[spl[0]] += spl[1:]
    for k,v in d.items():
        f.write("{} {}\n".format(k,",".join(v)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.0/scripts/csvjoin.html), it has a command line utility also which might be easier to use:

First install with:

```
pip install csvkit
```

Then:

```
csvjoin --outer file1.csv file2.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd `zip` then walk through them at the same time. Do some splitting and formatting, then write out to a new file as your going line-by-line

```
with open('text1.csv') as f1, open('text2.csv') as f2, open('merge.csv', 'w') as fOut:
    for line1, line2 in zip(f1, f2):
        name, val1 = line1.strip().split(',')
        val2 = line2.strip().split(',')[1]
        fOut.write('{}, {}, {}\n'.format(name, val1, val2))
```

Comment: @ScottHunter Indeed it is. Cumbersome if nothing else. Just the first thing that came to mind given the OP's use case.